# Bash : How to check in a file if there are any word duplicates

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with 6 character words in every line and I want to check if there are any duplicate words. I did the following but something isn't right:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    name=$line
    d=$( grep '$name' chain.txt  | wc -w )

    if [ $d -gt '1' ]; then 
    echo $d $name
    fi
done <$1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each word is on a new line, you can achieve this without looping:

```
$ cat chain.txt  | sort | uniq -c | grep -v " 1 " | cut -c9-
```

Comment: And if the words are not on separate lines, throw in another call to `tr` to convert spaces into newlines.

Comment: That is quite some chaining. Have you tried `sort chain.txt | uniq -d`

Comment: `sort chain.txt | uniq -c ` gave exactly the output I wanted, thanks : )

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` for that:

```
 awk -F'\n' 'found[$1] {print}; {found[$1]++}' chain.txt
```

Set the field separator to newline, so that we look at the whole line. Then, if the line already exists in the array `found`, print the line. Finally, add the line to the found array.

Note: If a line will only be suppressed once, so if the same line appears, say, 6 times, it will be printed 5 times.